# UA to GA4 transition - APOS live data gateway

Tags: sql, google-analytics-4, universal-analytics

I am currently in the process of moving from UA to GA4.

Currently we connect SAP Analytics Cloud to UA using an APOS Live Data Gateway. One of the SQL queries we used was:

```
SELECT Sessions, Users, Date, DeviceCategory, PageviewsPerSession
FROM Traffic
WHERE StartDate = '7daysAgo' AND EndDate = 'Today'
```

I want to replicate this again in GA4 but with the addition of "Hostname" as a filter, has anybody got any suggestions as to how to go about doing this.

I have tried several different ways to get this done but seem to get errors in the code that should work.